# Using Entity Framework 6 to delete from a junction table but leave the record in the lookup table

Tags: entity-framework

I have 2 tables, 1 main table, 1 junction table and 1 lookup table. It's a 1-to-many-to-1 relationship. I'm looking for a way to delete all the entries from the junction table only, without removing the lookup value.

An example of my tables are below

`Record` table

- id
- name

Junction table

- recordid
- lookupid

`Lookups` table

- lookupid
- lookupname

Currently I'm passing in an updated model and I'm trying to delete all the junction records before reading the new chosen values. So far everything I've tried deletes out the record from the lookup table as well.

```
 foreach (var lookup in recordFromDB.Lookups.ToList()) {
     _context.Lookups.Remove(DesignSoftware);
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - just using the `.Clear()` method on the navigation property should remove any navigation (a.k.a. "junction") entries - but not the actual `Lookups` entries:

```
recordFromDB.Lookups.Clear();
YourContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: @marc_c your an absolute genius mate.  Thank you so much

Comment: @RichardBanks: I was just struggling with the same task a few days ago :-)